# Can't Update Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, update-manager, lts

On the Ubuntu website, it says that if I want to update Ubuntu from 12.04 LTS to 12.10, I have to go into Update Manager and click 'Check', which won't work. It pops up saying, "There are no updates to install," or, "The software

Answer (score 0):

Try :
Open update manager-> setting and try to change the server to main server or server which suits you and the check for update. if don't work then try sudo apt-get update in terminal